# Jsoup simple selector code help needed please

Tags: selector, jsoup

I'm having a hard time getting the wanted info from a very simple code.

For example, I have no problem collecting my data within this simple code:

```
<HTML>
<TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=100%><TR class=FSS-data-row-highlight>
<TD>&nbsp;<A HREF="player.cgi?4686">Evgeni Malkin</A>, Pit (C/RW)</TD>
<TD class=FSS-data-right> 6 pts in last 2 GP&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</TABLE>
</HTML>
```

What I need is the 'Evgeni Malkin 6 pts in last 2' string which works fine within that code. But when connect to the whole page, it returns nothing. I guess it is because there are tables within tables but I can't figure out how to proceed. Here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forecaster.thehockeynews.com/hockeynews/hockey/statistics.cgi?mlb&mode=hotnot/").get();
Elements scanYearplace = doc.select("tr.FSS-data-row-highlight td");
String yearplace = scanYearplace.text();
```

In fact I need all to grab the infos on all the other players too but it would be a start if I could that one to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

--- see update below ---

Please realize this is a fragile in that any change to the site could potentially break this.  You'll also want to do some error checking and whatnot.  Also, I didn't see the "6 pts in last 2 GP" text like you have above, but you can grab whatever stat you want using this code.  Just change the `stats.get(4)` to whatever you want.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forecaster.thehockeynews.com/hockeynews/hockey/statistics.cgi?mlb&mode=hotnot/").get();

    for (Element e : doc.select(".FSS-data-row")) {
        Element td = e.select("td.FSS-data-left > a").first();
        String name = (td != null?td.text():null);
        Elements stats = e.select(".FSS-data-right");
        String goals = (stats.size() > 0?stats.get(4).text():null);
        System.out.println(name + ":" + goals);
    }
```

Sample output:

```
null:null
J. Benn:13
P. Sharp:20
P. Marleau:17
T. Oshie:14
```

The first null:null is because that is like the header row on the page.

---

### -----UPDATE-----

The url you had in your post pointed to the wrong page.  Here is updated code to get what I think you want..

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forecaster.thehockeynews.com/hockeynews/hockey/statistics.cgi?&mode=hotnot").get();
    for (Element e : doc.select("tr.FSS-data-row-highlight")) {
        Element tdname = e.select("td > a").first();
        String name = (tdname != null?tdname.text():null);
        Element tdstat = e.select("td.FSS-data-right").first();
        String stat = tdstat.text();
        System.out.println(name + ":" + stat);
    }
```

Sample output:

```
Mathieu Perreault:5 pts in last 2 GP 
Mikhail Grabovski:5 pts in last 2 GP 
James Neal:4 pts in last 2 GP 
Kris Versteeg:4 pts in last 2 GP 
Evgeni Malkin:12 pts in last 6 GP
```